# Continue JavaScript after open new Tab via Button Click

Tags: javascript, button, tabs

I'm quiet new to JavaScript and need your help concerning the following problem:
I've written a JavaScript to subscribe automatically to a gym class every monday at 7 a.m..
I have to click a button that's opening a new tab where I have to fill my personal data. The URL of the new tab is variable so I cant do it via

```js
window.open(URL,"_self")
```

Is there a way to continue the script in the new tab or open the website in the same tab?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that you are able to access the `window` of that URL due to [Cross-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: You cannot use your own javascript to work on external website. But you could investigate the gym to see how it submits the data. Then you can use CURL or even python to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the objections mentioned, that doesn't sound feasible to me - at least in this form. If you want to run a script on the external website, then simply use a browser solution such as:

- Tampermonkey (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
- Greasemonkey (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

There you can install your script and have it automatically fill out your registration.

If you want to automate this completely without doing anything on your part, then you will not be able to avoid an (external server-side) solution such as a NodeJS application with puppeteer (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) running every X days.